# Proving that $R_{(0)}$ is the field of fractions.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-writing, field-theory, localization

Here is the question I want the solution of part $(c)$ in it:

Let $R$ be an integral domain with field of fractions $K,$ and let $S \subset R \setminus \{0\}$ be a multiplicatively closed subset.

$(a)$ Show that $S^{-1}R = \{r/s \mid r \in R, s \in S\}$ is a subring of $K$ containing $R.$ $S^{-1}R$ is called the localization of $R$ at $S.$Note: If $S = \{ x^n \mid n \in \mathbb Z \}$ for prime $x \in R,$ then $S^{-1}R = R[x^{-1}].$

$(b)$  Show that if $\mathfrak{p} \subset R$ is a prime ideal, then  $S = R \setminus \mathfrak{p}$ is multiplicatively closed set. In this case the ring $S^{-1}R$ is denoted by $R_{\mathfrak{p}}.$

$(c)$ Since $R$ is an integral domain, $(0)$ is a prime ideal. What is $R_{(0)}$

**My question is:**

I know the solutions of letters $(a)$ and $(b),$ and I am guessing that from $(b),$ I can tell that $R_{(0)} = S^{-1}R = \{r/s \mid r \in R, s \in S\} $ and it is a subring of the field of fractions $K.$ I  know also from $(b)$ that $S = R\setminus (0) = R - \{0\}.$ but how can I show that $R_{(0)} = K$? could anyone show me a rigorous proof to this equality please?

Also, because $(0)$ is a prime ideal, then $R/(0)$ is an integral domain, but how can I collect all his information together to form a proof?

**Is the proof is just by showing that $1 \in S$**?

**My definition for the field of fraction of $R$:**

It is the smallest field containing $R$ as a subring.

Comment: Can you provide the definition of $R_{(0)}$ is question $(c)$?

Comment: oh sorry I will edit my question with part $(c)$ @mathcounterexamples.net

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I edited my question.

Comment: The idea is that $R_P$ is the ring where we invert everything not in $P$. So when $P=\langle 0\rangle$, we are inverting everything nonzero, which is precisely the field of fractions. I suppose a rigorous proof would also depend on your definition of the field of fractions.

Comment: @Dave Ok I will add my definition to my field of fraction to the question.

Comment: "The smallest field containing $R$ as a subring" means that the field of fractions satisfies some universal property. Show that the universal property holds for $R_{(0)}$.

Comment: How can I do that? @Marktmeister

Comment: Well, what does it mean that a field $K$ is the smallest field containing $R$ as a subring? It means that there is an injective map $\iota \colon R \to K$, such that for every field $L$ and every injective map $j \colon R \to L$, there is a unique injective map $h \colon K \to L$ such that the obvious diagram commutes, i.e., $j = h \circ \iota$. So you have to show that $R_{(0)}$ is a field and that the above condition is satisfied for $K = R_{(0)}$.